# Routine Presentation Template in Google Slides

Tags: google-slides

I make the same presentations with the same structure almost every day, week, month, quarter end.

I am having difficulty creating a template that I can just open up and fill out everyday.

What is the best way to approach this problem in terms of workflow?

How can I create my own "template?"

Answer (score 0):

(1) Create the Template

(2) Click File > Make a Copy

(3) Name new copy

(4) Close Template